# Embeded PowerPoint slideshow in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a SharePoint collaboration portal that is used a default intranet gateway. The requirement is to embed a PowerPoint presentation with this portal so that it cycles through all the slides in SP webpart, rather than using PowerPoint application. I have created a slide library and uploaded the presentation with an understanding that I can use an image webpart but that did not work (for obvious reasons).

Is there a way to accomplish this and how do I go about it. I can write a custom web part if I have to.

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

You already did what I would have suggested : exporting your presentation to a image gallery where each slide is an image. Now, you just need to create a rotating image webpart, either with some simple controls built-in (previous, next) or automatic (rotating, but I would go for a manual process).

Waldek created a nice walkthrough to simply create a rotating slide show : http://blog.mastykarz.nl/images-slideshow-sharepoint-2007-jquery/ using a list view webpart (as source) and a content query webpart with some javascript to transform the rendering of the list view.

You just need to pick a relevant "image slideshow" script from the thousands available in javascript and make sure that it's transforming your barebone list of images to something fancier.

Hope that helped.

Kindly.